# Goaccess log format for nginx

Tags: logging, nginx, goaccess

Here my logs

```
180.76.15.143 - - [09/Oct/2016:07:43:04 +0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.htm$
180.76.15.160 - - [09/Oct/2016:07:44:15 +0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.htm$
180.76.15.154 - - [09/Oct/2016:08:39:45 +0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.htm$
```

I use these format but doesn't work

```
time-format %H:%M:%S
date-format %d/%b/%Y
log-format %h - %^ [%d:%t %^]  "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %T "%^"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

NCSA Combined Log Format:

```
time-format %H:%M:%S
date-format %d/%b/%Y
log-format %h %^[%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Use these setting and works now!

time-format %H:%M:%S
date-format %d/%b/%Y
log-format %h - %^ [%d:%t %^]  "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %T "%^"